# Syntax errors in Eclipse

Tags: case, ide, eclipse

I have a case extension class, no modifications have recently been made, but whenever I open the file, I get a bunch of Syntax Errors in Eclipse. I am able to validate and deploy the class to salesforce without issue. All of the errors are about mismatched input expecting RPAREN or expecting SEMICOLON. The issue is only occurring in my case extension, my other extensions seem to be fine. After researching the issue, I was able to find a similar issue ([here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AcoEIAS)) on the developer forum with no answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the Summer '14 version of the Force.com IDE. (The code you link to doesn't produce any errors in the earlier version I am using.)

The "What's New in Summer '14" of the current [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) page includes this item (bolding added by me):

> Enabled **syntax checking** and outline view using **a new parser**, which can
>   be toggled through Preferences… > Force.com > Apex Parser.

The aim is presumably to be able to do a better job of the parsing without needing round trips to the server. But it sounds like the parser gets lost with some code (that the server is happy to accept).

While most of the Force.com IDE [source code is now available](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore), source code for classes like `ApexLexerImpl` and `ApexParserImpl` is not included. So its Salesforce who will need to fix this - you could raise a case with them including the problematic source code.

**PS**

The bug list that sfdcfox mentions is https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues?page=1&state=open and it looks like bug reports posted there are getting actioned so I suggest you post your code there after checking that the same problem hasn't already been reported. (Perhaps this https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/34 is the same bug?)

Comment: FWIW, I've logged a bug about the parser myself on GitHub. It seems the parser is not the Godsend we'd hoped for.

Comment: I am glad to see it's at least a known issue, I can ignore it for now since so far it only happens on one of my classes. Thanks guys!